# Using Only 3 out of 4 wires on 220 wire run

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit-breaker, 240v

I have equipment that has 3 wires (red, black, green)

The wire run from the breaker box is 10-3 (red, black, green, white)

The equipment requires 220/240v.
I'm just wondering if it's OK to leave the white wire capped off at the outlet?

Basically I have a red & black hot tied to the red and black (respectively) and ground to ground. The white (which is tied to the ground in the circuit breaker box) is just capped off by itself at the equipment.

Is this good, or should I cut the white off in the breaker box which would essentially make my 10-3 run of wire a 10-2?

Comment: Do _NOT_ cut it short - leave the full length stuffed in the back of the box! Someone, at some time _will_ need that (quite possibly future-you) and curse you for having cut it off!!

Answer (score 16):

### Go ahead and cap the unused white (neutral) wire off

Your plan to cap the unused white wire off is fine, and for the best even, as it'll leave it available in case someone else wishes to run a 4-wire appliance off this circuit in the future.

Answer (score 5):

You are fine with just capping off the white wire in the outlet box. Usually people here have the opposite problem: Needing a 4 wire feed and only have 3, you have a good problem! Which isn't exactly a problem.   If you want to be double/triple sure, remove the cover of your main panel and see where those wires land. Probably both the neutral and ground will  land on a neutral bus bar.

Comment: Thanks.  The ground and neutral in the panel are tied together.  I believe the both go to the neutral bar from there.

Comment: That's not quite "best practice" both the ground and neutral should be landed individually on the neutral / ground bar. Not critical, but certainly not best practice.

Comment: Ground should go to a grounding bar and neutral to a neutral bar.  Don't want neutral current (remember that there are other circuits!) flowing in the (typically smaller) ground wire, or an open neutral connection upstream resulting in an energized ground.

Comment: @Technophile What you said is mandatory in sub-panels, that the ground and neutral are isolated.   In a main panel, the neutrals and grounds often go to the same bus bar, which I don't do, but it is allowed.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson To be clear, you're saying you separate grounds and neutrals to separate bonding bars in the main panel, right? Not that you don't have bonded neutrals in the main panel?

Comment: After checking...  The ground and neutral Are separate.  And go to their respective bars.   Thanks to all for the Quick help!

Comment: @TylerH not quite. The OP said the neutral and ground were "tied together" and then attached, presumably by one wire to the neutral bus bar.  It works, but not a good practice and probably not code legal. More info:  The reason I put grounds on a separate bus (which is usually directly attached to the panel box) is that they are not expected to carry any current except in the case of a ground fault. Neutrals however are designed to carry quite a bit of current and I want them to have the best path possible back to the "grounded neutral conductor".

Comment: @TylerH  OK, I'm going on, but the other reason is if in the future somebody needs to turn a main panel into a sub-panel, like after a whole house generator transfer switch, it's far easier to do if the grounds and neutrals are on separate bus bars.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson No worries :-) I think I was just getting confused w/ the terminology regarding ground vs bus bar; It wasn't clear to me at first whether you were suggesting you didn't personally connect neutrals to ground at the main service panel. Think I'm clear now (e.g. at the main service panel, *either* a single *or* separate bus bars is fine, but they both have to be connected to ground).

Comment: @TylerH  Yeah, the terminology gets complex!  It took me a while to get my head around the difference between  "grounded neutral conductor" and "equipment grounding conductor".  The first is expected to carry some current, the second is not but is there in case of a ground fault.